# Discord Bot To Send A Message At A Certain Time

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am attempting to create a discord bot that sends a message in a server everyday at 8:00am local time with information about temperature, rain percentage, etc.

I am having trouble coming up with a way for the bot to check if it is 8:00am at the user's local time. I have a few helper methods that find the local current time that formats it to "HH:MM:SS".

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from userInfo import getCurrentTime


#prefix for a command, i.e. listens for keyword to announce message
intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)
token = "--------------------------"

# Prints a message to the terminal stating the bot is ready.
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("-------------------")
    print("The Bot Is Ready!")
    print("-------------------")

# For a user get information on bot
@client.command()   
async def info(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Hello, I am the Weather Pledge!")
    await ctx.send("I send out a location-based weather report every morning at 8am local time.")

# Test method 
if (getCurrentTime() == '08:00:00'):
    async def weather(ctx):
        await ctx.send("This is where I will put API JSON info")
        await ctx.send("This never prints.")

client.run(token)
```

Ive tried a few iterations of the "weather" function, where I start with async def weather(ctx) and  have the if statement in the method but I'm not sure if theres another method to call without having to initiate the bot with a command, as I have not seen any in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Tasks are exactly what you are looking for:
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html

You will have to learn some more Python. But this is the best way to accomplish what you want.

As for the timezones, you will have to have the users set their own timezone, there is no way to extract that info from discord. [pytz](https://pypi.org/project/pytz/) is a great timezone management module.

There are a few things wrong with your current function which is why it isn't working.

- It's missing a decorator - those lines with the `@` - which means it never gets registered with the bot
- Don't use an `if` statement to create a function (unless you know what you're doing). Your code only checks `getCurrentTime()` once, when you run the Discord bot. You would have to run your bot at exactly 8AM, down to the second, for the function to be created. If you ever want to check the time, do it inside of a function. But don't in this case, because you'd want to use Tasks for this anyways